# Не сохраняется сохраненная тема в LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, bom

Получается сделать смену темы на клик, но при обновлении страницы заданное значение не выгружается из LocalStorage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Chalarangelo/mini.css/v3.0.1/dist/mini-default.min.css">
  <style>
    .page {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .dark {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    .text {
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="page" id="page">
    <p id="text" >Я текст, меняющий цвет</p>
    <button id="switcher">Темный режим</button>
    <script>
        const page = document.getElementById('page');
        const text = document.getElementById('text');
        const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');
      
        let theme = '';
        let switcherLightDark = 0;
        let storage = '';
        localStorage.getItem('current', theme);
        switcher.onclick = function (){
          if ( switcherLightDark === 0) {
            switcherLightDark += 1;
            theme = 'dark';
            storage = localStorage.setItem('current', theme);
            page.classList.add('dark');
            text.classList.add('text'); 
            return;
          } 
          if (switcherLightDark === 1) {
            switcherLightDark -= 1;
            theme = 'light';
            storage = localStorage.setItem('current', theme);
            page.classList.remove('dark');
            text.classList.remove('text'); 
            return;
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Наверное потому что Вы нигде не проверяете какое у Вас значение хранится в локал сторедж на данный момент, а только записываете туда значение на клик и все. И логика с `switcherLightDark` не совсем ясна, зачем это?

Comment: Вы же сохраняете значение в локал сторедж, так и проверяйте, какое значение у Вас хранится в локал сторедж и в зависимости от этого добавляйте класс на загрузку страницы.

Answer (score 4):

Давайте разберемся, что в вашем коде не так и попытаемся сделать его гораздо лучше?

1. Куча переменных, которые вы создаете - не имеют смысла. Можно обойтись всего одной.
2. `localStorage.getItem('current', theme);` - метод `getItem` принимает только один параметр.
3. Вы при загрузке страницы ничего не делаете с "полученными" данными.

А теперь что можно сделать и как улучшить.

1. Для начала мы убираем все переменные и добавляем только `isDarkTheme`, она у нас будет булевая (т.е. true/false), и значение при загрузке будет из `localStorage`.
2. Сразу после этого мы дадим класс элементам, если наша переменная `isDarkTheme` равняется `true`. В данном случае мы можем воспользоваться вторым аргументом метода `toggle` у `classList`.
3. Мы переписали обработчик клика, теперь мы инвертируем значение переменной `isDarkTheme`, записываем новое значение в `localStorage` и переключаем классы у элементов.

Могут возникнуть вопросы, а зачем нужны эти `JSON` преобразования. Отвечу, значение в `localStorage` может быть только строкой, для этого мы переводим наше булевое значение в строку с помощью `JSON.stringify` и обратно с помощью `JSON.parse`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Chalarangelo/mini.css/v3.0.1/dist/mini-default.min.css">
  <style>
    .page {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .dark {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    .text {
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="page" id="page">
    <p id="text" >Я текст, меняющий цвет</p>
    <button id="switcher">Темный режим</button>
    <script>
        const page = document.getElementById('page');
        const text = document.getElementById('text');
        const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');
      
        let isDarkTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isDarkTheme"));
        
        page.classList.toggle('dark', isDarkTheme === true);
        text.classList.toggle('text', isDarkTheme === true); 

        switcher.onclick = function (){
          isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme;
          
          page.classList.toggle('dark', isDarkTheme === true);
          text.classList.toggle('text', isDarkTheme === true); 
          
          localStorage.setItem("isDarkTheme", JSON.stringify(isDarkTheme));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Мне вот интересно, кто поставил голос против и за что?

Comment: 1 голос за перевешивает целых 5 голосов против

Comment: Опечатка! Не `toogle`, а `toggle`.

Comment: @PetLinux, поправил опечатку. Да.. Конечно перевешивает, но только по репутации.

Comment: `isDarkTheme === true` - брррррр

Comment: @Qwertiy а что?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы получаете данные из localStorage неправильно. Вы пишете:

```
localStorage.getItem('current', theme);
```

Но когда мы получаем данные из localStorage с помощью getItem, в скобки нам нужно передавать всего один аргумент, а именно ключ, по которому мы создавали данный localStorage используя localStorage.setItem().

Вам нужно использовать метод localStorage.getItem() правильно для получения значения из хранилища и проверять его наличие. Для решения вашей проблемы я переписал ваш код и объяснил его ниже. Вот исправленный код:

```
const page = document.getElementById('page');
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');

let theme = localStorage.getItem('current');
if (theme === 'dark') {
  page.classList.add('dark');
  text.classList.add('text');
}

switcher.onclick = function () {
  if (theme === 'dark') {
    theme = 'light';
    localStorage.setItem('current', 'light');
    page.classList.remove('dark');
    text.classList.remove('text');
  } else {
    theme = 'dark';
    localStorage.setItem('current', 'dark');
    page.classList.add('dark');
    text.classList.add('text');
  }
};
```

Здесь мы получаем значение из LocalStorage в переменную `theme` и, если оно равно 'dark', применяем соответствующие классы к элементам страницы. Затем при клике на кнопку мы проверяем значение `theme` и в зависимости от него меняем классы и записываем новое значение в LocalStorage. Теперь при обновлении страницы оно будет выгружаться и применяться к элементам.

Comment: @PetLinux данный ответ достаточно прост и содержит в себе несколько элементарных действий со скриптами и localStorage, которые можно было бы осуществить даже без знаний программирования. Жду от вас доказательства своих слов, а так же доказательства того, что мой код не рабочий, иначе восприму данный комментарий за обвинение и определенного рода агрессию. Я попытался дать максимально простой и короткий ответ в данном вопросе, так как при поиске вопросов в stackoverflow через поисковые системы самому не очень охотно было читать огромные тексты. У новичков такое бывает.Мой ответ был неправильным?

Comment: Да и хочется ответить прямо, а не лить лишней воды, словно на лекции сидишь, в интернете есть и так полно  ответов о том, что такое localStorage и как им пользоваться, в данном же случае я попытался дать конкретный ответ на конвретный вопрос.

Comment: **Это не ответ от нейросети**, и да, я уже сделал это. Давайте не будем заполнять комменты ненужной информацией. Хорошего дня.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146868/discussion-between-pet-linux-and-kenan).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за такой полный ответ, я и правда только начинаю, даже простые действия пока для меня сложноваты, но я стараюсь)

Comment: @Павел перечитайте, пожалуйста, я в начале кое-что исправил, если остались вопросы, готов помочь.

Comment: Ребят, вы чёт разошлись и не по делу. А как насчёт создать функцию темы и не городить огород в функции клика, при этом запускать функцию темы при загрузки страницы?
Вот где была бы простота кода, а сейчас от вас только трёп...

Answer (score -1):

```js
let chkbox = document.getElementById('chkbox');
let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || '';
document.body.className = theme;
chkbox.checked = theme !== '';
chkbox.addEventListener('change',function(){
  theme = this.checked ? 'dark' : '';
  localStorage.setItem('theme',theme);
  document.body.className = theme;
})
```

```css
body.dark {
  background: #2d2d2d;
}

.dark .text{
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
 <label for='chkbox' class='text'>Цветовая схема</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="chkbox">
```

Альтернатива с использование атрибута theme.

```js
let chkbox = document.getElementById('chkbox');
let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || '';
document.body.setAttribute('theme',theme);
chkbox.checked = theme !== '';
chkbox.addEventListener('change',function(){
  theme = this.checked ? 'dark' : '';
  localStorage.setItem('theme',theme);
  document.body.setAttribute('theme',theme);
})
```

```css
body[theme=dark] {
  background: #2d2d2d;
}

[theme=dark] .text{
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
 <label for='chkbox' class='text'>Цветовая схема</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="chkbox">
```

Comment: Почему событие `click`, а не `change`? И не красиво затирать все классы у элементов.

Comment: @OliverPatterson по клику поправил, изначально кнопка была, потому клик остался. А вот насчет classname и classlist и красиво/некрасиво - дело сугубо индивидуальное. Я применяю classname или classlist по ситуации. В данном случае classname применяется к body. А там как правило много классов не часто вешается. Поэтому так быстрее и короче.По крайней мере не isDarkTheme === true, если уж  говорить про красиво/некрасиво )